# Reshaping a dataframe by splitting list to append rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to reshape my dataframe please (split the list to new rows):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [[1,2], [1,2], 3], 'B': [x, y, z]})

    A       B
0   [1, 2]  x
1   [1, 2]  y
2   3       z
```

to the desired output:

```
out = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'B': [x, x, y, y, z]})

   A  B
0  1  x
1  2  x
2  1  y
3  2  y
4  3  z
```

Row order doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode`

```
df = df.explode('A')
```

**Output**

```
   A  B
0  1  x
0  2  x
1  1  y
1  2  y
2  3  z
```